# How to remove docker images which created 7 days ago automatically?

Tags: image, shell, docker, cron

Is there a way to remove built docker images some days ago?

If we check `docker images`, will got:

```
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

There exists a `CREATED` item.

Researched from the [official document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/), didn't find an option for that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) provides a filter to remove images until a specific date:

```
docker image prune -a --filter "until=$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' --date='-15 days')"
```

Comment: Or this way: `docker images --filter=reference='myregistry/myrepo*' | grep "7 days ago" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker image rm`

Comment: @vv, the above command will only remove images which are `7 days` old. Older than 7 days images remain there so this solution is not the answer of the original question.

Answer (score 35):

You can tell docker image prune to delete any images older than a given number of hours, in your case: 7 * 24h= 168h.

```
docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=168h"
```

With the option --force, there won't be any prompt so it can easily be added to a crontab to be run on a daily basis.

For this, open crontab in edit mode (`crontab -e`) and add the following line to run this command every day at 1am.

```
0 1 * * * docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=168h"
```

Comment: While I like Docker's filter functionality, I'm disappointed that the logical negation of `until` isn't supported (e.g., a `since` keyword). A bit half-assed IMO.

Comment: @will right? People spin up docker containers for one-off and exploratory purposes all the time and want to trash them shortly thereafter, and yet docker still assumes - foolishly IMO - that you always want to discard the oldest, or just you love manually creating a long list of IDs to manually discard.

Answer (score 9):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/

`docker image prune -a --force --filter "until=240h"`