# Updating a docker container from image; leaves old images on server

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-image

My process for updating a docker image to `production` (a docker swarm) is as follows:

**On `dev` environment:**

`docker-compose build`

`docker push myrepo/name`

**Then on the `prod` server, which is a docker swarm:**

`docker pull myrepo/name`

`docker service update --image myrepo/name --with-registry-auth containername`

This works perfectly; the swarm is updated with the latest image.

However, it always leaves the old image on the live servers and I'm left with something like this:

`docker image ls`

```
REPOSITORY                   TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
myrepo/name                  latest      abcdef         14 minutes ago   1.15GB
myrepo/name                  <none>      bcdefg         4 days ago       1.22GB
myrepo/name                  <none>      cdefgh         6 days ago       1.22GB
```

Which, over time results in a heap of disk space being unnecessarily used.

I've read that `docker system prune` is not safe to run on `production` especially in a swarm.

So, I am having to regularly, manually remove old images e.g.

`docker image rm bcdefg cdefgh`

Am I missing a step in my update process, or is it 'normal' that old images are left over to be manually removed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: add a cmd line at the end of your script to delete the old docker image

Comment: So you're suggesting the ^^ behaviour of leaving old images is 'normal'? it doesn't seem right to me. And what cmd could I add to delete old images?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737059/how-to-remove-docker-images-which-created-7-days-ago-automatically

Answer (score 1):

since you are using docker swarm and probably multi node setup you could deploy a global service which would do the cleanup for you. We are using Bret Fisher's approach on it:

```
    version: '3.9'

    services:
      image-prune:
        image: internal-image-registry.org/proxy-cache/library/docker:20.10
        command: sh -c "while true; do docker image prune -af --filter \"until=4h\"; sleep 14400; done"
        networks:
          - bridge
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        deploy:
          mode: global
        labels:
          - "env=devops"
          - "application=cleanup-image-prune"

    networks:
      bridge:
        external: true
        name: bridge
```

When adding new hosts it gets deployed automatically on it with our own base docker image and then does the cleanup job for us.

We are still missing some time to inspect newer docker service types which are scheduled on their own. It would probably be wise to move cleanup jobs to the global service replicated jobs provided by docker instead of an infinite loop in a script. It just works for us so we did not make it high priority enough to swap over to it. More info on the [replicated jobs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#running-as-a-job)