# Artifactory CLI delete files

Tags: json, docker, artifactory

I have docker layers in Artifactory. I want to delete the files / layers that are "4w" old, and keep the other ones that are older then "4w".
Is there any way to achieve that with "jf rt" and the AQL json file?

Thank you in advance!

I read the documentation but I was not able to find a way how to achieve that.

Comment: Is  your problem similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/50737059/9475509?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete old images using file specs like this:

```
jfrog rt del --spec=<mySpecfile>
```

Where the file spec is:

```
{ "files": [  {

 "aql": {

    "items.find" : {

      "repo":"<DOCKER_REPO_NAME>",

      "$and": [{

          "created":{"$before":"4w"},

      }]   }}}]}
```

It is always recommended to use the [dry-run](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-cli/example-2?tocId=8MeG9vLv9uHOVDADU1PZwg) option first to ensure it deletes the correct files.
[This KB](https://jfrog.com/help/r/how-to-clean-up-old-docker-images/resolution) has more info on this method and an additional Python cleanup script. And the [documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/relative-time-operators-in-aql) has more info on Relative Time Operators in AQL.