Docker cache is using too much space
Over time, Docker on the server begins to fill up too much space (apparently because of the build cache). This can be solved using the docker system prune, but maybe there is some way to set a limit for this cache so that it does not take up more space than it should, or somehow clear only old and irrelevant caches so as not to lose build speed?
How is it generally accepted to solve this problem?

Probably not the answer you wanted, but I'd use a scheduled task/CRON job/whatever to delete old/unused images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737059/how-to-remove-docker-images-which-created-7-days-ago-automatically
